# Open already running program via terminal

Tags: command-line

How do I switch to already running program using terminal?

For examaple:

`firefox` opens new firefox window.

Is there a command that will focus the already opened firefox window?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, I think you wanted to focus an existing window, not open a new window. I've submitted an edit to clarify, but it's pending review.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### As a one- liner

Assuming you have [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) installed (run `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` if not):

The command:

```
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep gedit)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

Would raise the *last* opened `gedit` window. Replace it by any other application.

#### Explanation

```
pgrep gedit
```

gets the pid of gedit

```
wmctrl -lp
```

lists all windows and the pid they belong to

```
awk '{ print $1 }'
```

splits off the window- id (the first string in the line)

```
$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep gedit)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

therefore finds the window-id of the last created window of `gedit` (the output of `wmctrl -lp` lists the windows in a chronological order of creation, if the application has multiple windows, `tail -1` returns the last one).

```
wmctrl -ia
```

subsequently raises the window by its `window-id`

#### In a small script

...to be run with the application as argument:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep "$1")" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

- Save it into an empty file as `switchto.sh`
- Make it executable
- Run it as (e.g.)

  ```
  /path/to/switchto.sh firefox
  ```

#### Alternatives?

*Theoretically* the command:

```
xdotool search --class gedit windowactivate
```

should do (kind of) the same; it should raise the *first found* window of `gedit` in this case. 
It seems less robust however. On my system (Unity) it did nothing at all.

Comment: I found this interesting, however, it fails sometime. Adding one more line could improve it a bit more.. it will first check `gedit` is running or not then there will be less error:

`if ps -e | grep gedit ;then echo "gedit is running"; else gedit; fi;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have runned firefox using `firefox &` you can use `jobs` to see its number. To bring it to foreground write `%n firefox` which `n` stands for its number. Example:

```
sabrina@ubuntu:~$ jobs
[1]+ Stopped      firefox
sabrina@ubuntu:~$ fg %1
```

Also you can "kill" the program:

```
sabrina@ubuntu:~$ kill %1
```

Answer (score -1):

It's just an improvement to the great answer from Jacob. I have just used conditional statement. Also, I was having weird behavior with `$1`, so I just hard-coded a program. In my case, it's `dolphin` file manager that I want to run only instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
RUNONCE=dolphin
if (ps -e | grep -w $RUNONCE) ;
then wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep "$RUNONCE")" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $RUNONCE }')";
else $RUNONCE
fi;
```